# Where do I see the data on goals collected?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager set up and working in the console and the `data.layer` events are firing okay. I have entered my Analytics ID as well.

Where do I see the data on the goals collected from the tag manager?

Comment: You login in to www.google.com/analytics and click on the profile you are sending the data to and look in the google analytics reports

Comment: thanks do you know which part of the reports they show in?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please? The GTM events are generally used for tag firing logic (as far as I am aware). Are you triggering any events that you have defined as goals in GA with these?

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert with GA, which is why I'm asking for help; Thank you! So the tags that are fired on tag manager must also be defined as goals on GA? here is example code I'm using - dataLayer.push({'event': 'clickFriendUser'});
What goal should I add in GA for this? Many Thanks